# Filtered Access 2010 Report Shows All Results

Tags: sql, ms-access, filter, report, ms-access-2010

I have a report based in Access 2010 that prints information on a project. There are two subreports: one that lists all the projects under the criteria searched for, and one that actually prints the information. When I search for one project, the second subreports only prints the one, but the first lists all the projects.

Basically, I need to filter this SQL so that it only lists the projects under the project number (ProjNo) searched for. I'm not very good at SQL so any assistance would be appreciated.

```
SELECT Index.ProjNo, Index.Year, Index.Route, Index.Area, Index.[Value], Index.[Costs], Index.Page, Val(Nz([route],0)) AS routeNum
FROM [Index];
```

EDIT: I also need it to show all the projects when the user doesn't search for a specific one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WHERE clause should filter your report. Try changing "your search" to the appropriate value in your application.

```
SELECT Index.ProjNo
, Index.Year
, Index.Route
, Index.Area
, Index.[Value]
, Index.[Costs]
, Index.Page
, Val(Nz([toute],0)) AS routeNum
FROM [Index]
WHERE (((Index.ProjNo) = your search));
```

Comment: Okay now I'm having a problem where if I don't search by project - if I want it to bring up all the projects - the list only prints the last project searched for instead of all of them.

Comment: A combobox. But it isn't always used. If I search by projno, this works perfectly. If I leave it blank, though, and search for all the projects it only shows me one of them. I don't know if that clarifies the problem...

Comment: This sounds very similar to your report: [click here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-access/form-displays-some-data-before-combo-box-selection/0368f065-dbb3-4fed-8e8a-2ab7b2481920). If you remove the WHERE clause from your SQL too.

Comment: It seems like the link is doing the opposite of what my report does. From what I understand, that one starts with a blank report and then makes a selection, whereas mine makes the selection from a separate form and then opens the report. It doesn't seem like this will work for me.